# Java installed and configured but unable to run

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I have OpenJDK 8 installed and configured in the path, but when I try to run Java (such as running a JAR), I get the error:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

When I try installing default-jre, openjdk-8-jre, and openjdk-8-jre-headless I get an error saying that they're already installed. What could be the problem?

Comment: can you please try the command `which java`

Comment: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`